# Compiling a simple character device driver as a module

Tags: compiling, embedded, drivers

I wrote a simple character device driver & wanted to cross-compile it for craneboard (ARM architecture). My file name is `gDev.c`. I copied the file to `kernel/drivers/char` directory in craneboard source. I modified the `Kconfig` file in that same directory & added the following lines to it.

```
config TEST_GCHARD
    tristate "My Character driver"
    default m
```

I added the following line to the Makefile in the same directory.

```
obj-$(CONFIG_TEST_GCHARD)   += gDev.o
```

I added the following line in the `am3517_crane_defconfig` in `arch/arm/configs` directory.

```
CONFIG_TEST_GCHARD=m
```

My problem is, when I set it as `m` in `am3517_crane_defconfig`, the file is not getting included for compilation. But, if I change it as `y`, it is getting compiled. But, I need it to be a module which I must `insmod` after board boots up. Please guide me whether I'm missing any steps.

Comment: Does that kernel have modules enabled?

Comment: @CL. Thanks. How to check that?

Comment: @CL. I checked using `lsmod` and it listed the loaded modules. Then, I suppose, the kernel has modules enabled.

Comment: Where in the `Kconfig` file did you add it?

Comment: @CL. I added it as last but one entry. I'm able to see it in `menuconfig` also.